# Spiral Matrix Of Numbers with JavaScript... problems with the result

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an inverse circular matrix (from the large number to the small number that will be in the middle) of the numbers ... but I am faced with a problem: I cannot display it on the screen. The user enters the number N and pressing the button the matrix must be formed ...

But it does not work.... Help me please...
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body style="background-color:#bf8b99;" align="center">
<h1>CONSTRUCTOR</h1>
<h2>INPUT NUMBER</h2>

<form>

  <input type="text" name="a" size="15" id="a">

</form><br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="create()">CREATE</button>
<div id="test"></div>

<script>

function create(){
    a=parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
    document.body.style.background = "green";

    var spiral = [a][a];
        var value = 1; 
        var minCol = 0;
        var maxCol = a-1;
        var minRow = 0;
        var maxRow = a-1;

        while (value <= a*a)
        {
            for (int i = minCol; i <= maxCol; i++)
            { spiral[minRow][i] = value;               
                value++;
            }

            for (int i = minRow+1; i <= maxRow; i++) 
            { spiral [i][maxCol] = value;            
                value++; 
            } 

            for (int i = maxCol-1; i >= minCol; i--)
            { spiral[maxRow][i] = value;                      
                value++;
            }

            for (int i = maxRow-1; i >= minRow+1; i--) 
            { spiral[i][minCol] = value;
                value++;
            }      
            minCol++;
            minRow++;          
            maxCol--;           
            maxRow--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < spiral.length; i++)
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < spiral.length; j++)
            {
              document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = spiral[i][j] + "\t";
            }
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put the code into Glitch or codesandbox - and also say what it *does* do right now...

Comment: `var spiral = [a][a];` is not doing what you think.

Comment: There are other errors. You start up filling row 0, which is already wrong: that is not where number 1 will end up. At the end you overwrite `innerHTML` in each iteration. That cannot be what you intended either...

Comment: The button's text is also misleading. You are not dealing with the input as if it is a power of 2: you still raise it to that power with `a*a`...

Comment: The picture with the expected result is not like the arrows above it: it misses a top row (the matrix is not square). Can you clarify? Are you there?? You write "help me please", but you don't reply to comments...

Comment: I was gone. Thanks for the detailed answer that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code:

- `var spiral = [a][a]` is not doing what you think. It does not define a 2D array with a width and height of `a`. Instead it creates a 1-dimensional array with one value (*a*) in it. Then it accesses an index of that array only to find it does not have that index `a`. And so `spiral` is assigned `undefined`.
- You start filling up row 0, which is already the wrong place: that is not where number 1 will end up in the final result, yet you leave it there.
- At the end you overwrite `innerHTML` in each iteration. That cannot be what you intended either... It is better to prepare the matrix, and then turn that first into a string, and then finally assign that to the DOM (better with `textContent` than `innerHTML`).
- The `\t` character will not render any different than a space when you assign it to the `innerHTML` of a `div` without further CSS styling. You will get a better result when you use a `pre` element, which retains white-space (or do it with CSS), and so you can pad each output number with the required number of spaces to align it (use `padStart`).
- The button's text is also misleading. You are not dealing with the input as if it is a power of 2: you still raise it to that power with `a*a`...

Here is a solution that uses recursion: if the given width is 1 or 2 just return the hard-coded solution (base case). If greater, then solve the problem for a width that is two units less, and then wrap that result with one extra number on all sides. It is not so hard to find the mathematical invariant to do this last step.

Here is a snippet:

```js
function createSpiral(n) {
    if (n === 1) return [[1]];
    if (n === 2) return [[3, 4],
                         [2, 1]];
    let spiral = createSpiral(n-2);
    // add a prefix and a postfix number to those rows:    
    let start = n*(n-1);
    let end = (n-2)*(n-2) + 1;
    for (let row of spiral) {
        row.unshift(start--);
        row.push(end++);
    }
    // add extra row at top and bottom
    start = n*(n-1)+1;
    spiral.unshift(spiral[0].map(() => start++));
    end = n*(n-2)+2;
    spiral.push(spiral[0].map(() => end--));
    return spiral;
}

// I/O handling

let input = document.querySelector("#width");
let output = document.querySelector("#spiral");

function refresh() {
    let n = +input.value;
    // Validate input
    if (!(n >= 1 && n < 100)) return; 
    // Perform the algorithm
    let spiral = createSpiral(n);
    // Format the returned spiral to a nicely formatted string
    let digits = (n*n+"").length;
    output.textContent = spiral.map(row => row.map(i => (""+i).padStart(digits)).join(" ")).join("\n");
}

input.addEventListener("input", refresh);
refresh();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="width" max="99" min="1" value="5">
<pre id="spiral"></pre>
```

Comment: I was gone. Thanks for the detailed answer that works perfectly. Now I have to analyze and understand how it works. I'm a beginner in JS, I'm studying...

Answer (score 1):

For a spiral, you could take some iteration who are running betwin the sides and by checking the left over padding sizes.

```js
function spiral(length) {
    var upper = 0,
        lower = length - 1,
        left = 0,
        right = length - 1,
        i = upper,
        j = left,
        result = Array.from({ length }, _ => []),
        value = length * length;

    while (true) {
        if (left++ > right) break;

        for (; i < lower; i++) result[i][j] = value--;
        if (lower-- < upper) break;

        for (; j < right; j++) result[i][j] = value--;
        if (right-- < left) break;

        for (; i > upper; i--) result[i][j] = value--;
        if (upper++ > lower) break;

        for (; j > left; j--) result[i][j] = value--;
    }

    result[i][j] = value--;
    return result;
}

var target = document.getElementById('out'),
    i = 10;

while (--i) target.innerHTML += spiral(i).map(a => a.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2)).join(' ')).join('\n') + '\n\n';
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate a lot.